# Module ngx_http_realip_module and how to set_real_ip_from

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a very basic question about Module ngx_http_realip_module. I checked the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) and I saw this example:

```
set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;
set_real_ip_from  192.168.2.1;
set_real_ip_from  2001:0db8::/32;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

I also understand that these are:

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
set_real_ip_from <your VPC IPV4 CIDR here>;
set_real_ip_from <your VPC IPV6 CIDR here>;
```

My question is this: If my IPV4 that I use to connect to the server is: 123.12.12.123. Where do I get the number(s) /24 after that to make it: 123.12.12.123/24?
The same question applies to IPV6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `192.168.1.0/24` is the CIDR notation. `/24` indicates the number of bits in your network mask. `/24` corresponds to the network mask `255.255.255.0`. See [CIDR Notation article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) for details.